# Earth Engine - Why can't I add an imageCollection to a ui.Select()?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

When I create an ImageCollection, I would like to select the images from a select box, and then load them onto the map when selected.

```
var myImageCollection  = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_RT");

var myImages = myImageCollection.limit(10)
var myImage = myImages.first()


Map.centerObject(myImage,9)
Map.addLayer(myImage)

var selector = ui.Select(myImages())
```

Following this, I would add a `selector.onChange()` to change the images that are viewed on the map.

However when I run this part of the code, I get the following error.

```
The argument provided to ui.List.reset() must be an array.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the code having to do with the user interface must be local variables.  imageCollection is a server variable.

To implement the solution the `ui.Select` must be initialised with local values.

```js
var myImageCollection  = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_RT");

var myImages = myImageCollection.limit(10)
var myImage = myImages.first()


Map.centerObject(myImage,9)
Map.addLayer(myImage)

/////////////////Added Code //////////
function getIds(collection) {
  var info = collection.getInfo() // turns the collection to a local list
  var images = info['features'] // need to use local javascript to access
  var ids = []
  for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {  // note .length not size()
    var im = images[i]                   // [i] not .get(i)
    var id = im['id']
    ids.push(id)                       // note .push() not .cat()
  }
  return ids
}

print(getIds(myImages))

var selector = ui.Select(getIds(myImages)) // this turns myImages to a local list
print(selector)// adds selector to the console
```

Many thanks to Rodrigo E. Principe for giving me the correct information to build this answer.